# Custom post type term name not slug

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, slug

I am using custom post types with categories on my page. In my taxonomy-group.php, I have the following code to get the term as a title:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms('Abteilung');
echo '<h1 class="page-title">' .$term .'</h1>';
?>
```

But it does get the slug, not the name. For example, I have a name called "Service & Assembling", but what is shown is the permalink/slug "service-assembling" which does not look that nice as a title.

Comment: Where is `$term` coming from? You have set the `$terms` variable but you don't show how you are getting `$term`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `taxonomy-group.php` you need to access the queried object which is the current object of the specific term being viewed.

So you can try the following: (*Requires at least PHP 5.4 due to direct array dereferencing*)

```
$term_name = get_queried_object()->name;
echo '<h1 class="page-title">' .$term_name .'</h1>';
```

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score -1):

How to use [`get_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

```
<?php $terms = get_terms('Abteilung');
echo '<h1 class="page-title">' .$terms->name .'</h1>';
?>
```

Comment: You should also read that specific page. Your code will give a warning which will state that you cannot use an object as a string, neither is name a valid property of `$terms`